# VHDL: Assigning one std_logic_vector to another makes '1' turn to 'X'

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have a baffling problem.. As part of a buffering process I am assigning one std_logic_vector to another, by simply doing:

```
dataRegister <= dataRegisterBuf;
```

The process is synced to a clock. See here for the full process:

```
--! This process buffers the data register synced to sclk when state is state_bufferingToSclk and sets registerReady when done
SclkDomainBuffering: process(sclk)
variable step: natural := 0;
begin
    if (rising_edge(sclk)) then
        if (state = state_bufferingToSclk) then
            if (step = 0) then
                dataRegister <= dataRegisterBuf;
                step := 1;
            elsif (step = 1) then
                registerReady <= '1';
                step := 2; 
            end if;
        else
            step := 0;
            registerReady <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process SclkDomainBuffering;
```

The problem is, when simulating this in Modelsim, dataRegister does not take the value of dataRegisterBuf, instead every '1' in the vector becomes 'X'. So for example if dataRegisterBuf is "00010", dataRegister becomes "000X0". I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here is a simulation showing it happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEH5y.png

I have stepped through the entire code and I can't see anything out of the ordinary. At the time it happens, line 84 in the code above does indeed execute, and that is the only statement that is executed that has anything to do with the two registers in question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text (not a picture) in the question.

Comment: Tell us what else is driving `dataRegister`. (Use the "drivers" command in your simulator if you need to). NOTE : two or more drivers on a signal, without arbitration logic, is usually a bad idea.

Comment: The relevant code would be a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The problem is not reproducible from what you've shown.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. the symptoms you describe suggest you are driving `dataRegister` (to all zeros) from some other process.

Comment: The drivers command indeed show that there is another process driving the register, however that process is only active during a different state. I may be misunderstanding how signal assignment work in processes, if I do x <= y in a process once, will that continue to drive x even after the process exits?

Comment: will that continue to drive x even after the process exits? Yes. Absolutely. You are designing hardware here, not writing software. Think of each process (or concurrent assignment) as being a bit of SW that models a bit of HW. If you assign to a signal anywhere in that process, that process (ie that bit of HW) will drive that signal for all time. When a line in a process with a signal assignment is executed that merely defines what value that process is driving on to the signal. So, if you drive a signal from 2 processes, you have 2 bits of HW with their outputs shorted together.

Comment: BTW: You don't need brackets around the expression in an `if` statement (the `then` does the same job). As I tell my students, writing `if (step = 0) then` instead of `if step = 0 then` makes you look like an amateur. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I know it's describing hardware, I just kind of assumed if I started driving something from elsewhere it would automatically stop the other driver by using a tristate buffer or something, I don't know. It's hard to get in the right mindset. 

Also, I know I don't need the brackets, but I like it. I think it looks more readable. Is it frowned upon?

Comment: Your other process appears to be driving dataRegister to "00000000000000000000000000000000".

Comment: If you want tristate outputs you encode them yourself, e.g. `if thisProcessActive then dataRegister <= Data; else dataRegister <= (others => 'Z'); end if;`. But FPGAs generally only allow that on external I/O pins nowadays (since the late 1990s!). So moving all driving logic for a signal into the same process is the best way.

Comment: Whether you put brackets in or not is a matter of taste. In my experience beginners tend to put them in whilst people who know what they're doing, don't. Then are often required in other languages to enable the compiler to tell when the test expression stops and the next line of code starts. In VHDL the `then` does that job, so they are not required.

Comment: Matthew: I just asked in class today and both my professors say they personally prefer brackets over no brackets. They both have long experience with VHDL, not just academically. So I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) created from your question and comments:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity baffling_problem is
end entity;

architecture foo of baffling_problem is
    type state_type is (state_bufferingToClk, state_bufferingToSclk);
    signal state: state_type;  -- defaults to 'LEFT, state_bufferingToClk
    signal dataRegisterBuf:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) :=
                (1 | 2 => '1', others => '0');
    signal dataRegister:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal registerReady:       std_logic;
    signal sclk:                std_logic := '1';
begin

    SclkDomainBuffering: process(sclk)
    variable step: natural := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(sclk)) then
            if (state = state_bufferingToSclk) then
                if (step = 0) then
                    dataRegister <= dataRegisterBuf;
                    step := 1;
                elsif (step = 1) then
                    registerReady <= '1';
                    step := 2; 
                end if;
            else
                step := 0;
                registerReady <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process SclkDomainBuffering;
    SOMEOTHERPROCESS:
    process (state)
    begin
        if state = state_type'LEFT then  -- other than state_bufferingToSclk
            dataRegister <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        sclk <= '0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        sclk <= '1';
        wait for 0 ns;   -- state transitions in distinct delta cycle
        state <= state_bufferingToSclk;
        wait for 20 ns;
        sclk <= '0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        sclk <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

And this gives the behavior your describe:

[image: baffling_problem.png]

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3 Propagation of signal values, 14.7.3.1 General:

> As simulation time advances, the transactions in the projected output waveform of a given driver (see 14.7.2) will each, in succession, become the value of the driver. When a driver acquires a new value in this way or as a result of a force or deposit scheduled for the driver, regardless of whether the new value is different from the previous value, that driver is said to be active during that simulation cycle. For the purposes of defining driver activity, a driver acquiring a value from a null transaction is assumed to have acquired a new value. A signal is said to be active during a given simulation cycle if
>   — One of its sources is active.
>   — One of its subelements is active.
>   — The signal is named in the formal part of an association element in a port association list and the corresponding actual is active.
>   — The signal is a subelement of a resolved signal and the resolved signal is active.
>   — A force, a deposit, or a release is scheduled for the signal.
>   — The signal is a subelement of another signal for which a force or a deposit is scheduled.

So the signals (dataReady(1) and dataReady(2) are active their sources is active.

An explanation of why their values are the resolved value of their drivers is found in 14.7.3.2 Driving values, none of the signals comprising dataReady are basic signals, see paragraph 3 f).

And why you see the value of dataReady as "00000000000000000000000000000XX0" is described in 14.7.3.3 Effective values.

The VHDL language describes how an elaborated design model is simulated as well as describing the syntax and semantics.  An elaborated design model consists of processes described in a hierarchy interconnected by signals, and signals have history not just value. Signal updates are scheduled in projected output waveforms (see 10.5 Signal assignment statement).

A lot of users just starting out in VHDL apply what they know of the behavior of other languages to VHDL, an example is the superfluous (but not forbidden) parentheses surrounding a condition in an if statement. Knowledge of other languages doesn't address signal behaviors (determined by the architecture of simulation models driven by simulation cycles.

One of the things you'll note is that processes (11.3) suspend and resume based on explicit or implicit wait statements (10.2).

All concurrent statements are elaborated into processes and or processes and block statements (11. Concurrent statements).

Subprogram calls are either expressions (functions, 9.3.4) or statements (procedures, 10.7).

No signal value is updated while any process that is scheduled to be active (those projected output waveforms matching the current simulation time, 14.7.4 Model execution, 14.7.3.4 Signal update).

Signals driven in multiple processes represent multiple collections of hardware. The problem shows up because you've used resolved data types, if you had used unresolved data types you would have gotten an elaboration error instead (6.4.2.3 Signal declarations, paragraph 8). Resolved signals are allowed to have multiple drivers.

The resolution table for std_logic elements is found in the package body for package std_logic_1164(See footnote 15 Annex A Description of accompanying files for access to the source of VHDL packages included with the standard). The resolution table will resolve a '0' and a '1' to an 'X'.

And if all this sounds complex you can learn simple rules of thumb to prevent problems.

In this case a rule of thumb would be to always drive a signal from a single process.

Answer (score 1):

As people in the comments said, the problem was that another process was driving the same data register. I did not understand that even though that other process only changed the value of the register in a different state, it would still drive the signal during every other state. I fixed the problem by moving everything related to that register into a single process.